# OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: python, tensorflow

found a lot of posts related to this error, but didnt find a solution.

When i start my training i get the following error:

> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
>        [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_DOUBLE, DT_DOUBLE], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

The important code-parts are the following:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs_path/run5", graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord) 
    for e in range(10):
        _, summary = sess.run([train_step, summary_op])
        writer.add_summary(summary, e)
```

My pipeline functions are the following:

1)

```
def get_inputs(batch_size):
    filenames = []
    for ch in range(num_channels):
        for i in range(1):
            filenames.append(os.path.join(pipeline_path, "training_ch%d_%d_pipeline.bin" % (ch+1, i)))

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

    read_input = _read_pipeline_files(filename_queue)

    return _generate_spectrum_label_batch(read_input.spectrum, read_input.label, 1, batch_size, False)
```

2)

```
def _read_pipeline_files(queue):
    class PipelineRecord(object):
        pass
    result = PipelineRecord()

    reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=2*8*257)
    result.key, value = reader.read(queue)

    record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float64)

    result.spectrum = tf.reshape(tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [257]), [257])
    result.label = tf.reshape(tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [8*257], [2*257]), [257])

    return result
```

3)

```
def _generate_spectrum_label_batch(spectrum, label, min_queue_examples, batch_size, shuffle):
    if shuffle:
        spectrum_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([spectrum, label],
                                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                                             num_threads=8,
                                                             capacity=min_queue_examples + 3*batch_size,
                                                             min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
    else:
        spectrum_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([spectrum, label],
                                                     batch_size=batch_size,
                                                     num_threads=1,
                                                     capacity=min_queue_examples + 3*batch_size)

    return spectrum_batch, label_batch
```

I checked the path for the data (as per [OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 5, current size 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762532/outofrangeerror-see-above-for-traceback-fifoqueue-1-batch-fifo-queue-is-cl)) several times. The path should be right! The .bin-data is there. I have no idea how to debug that.
I changed batch_size several times, nothing happened.

Thank you :)

Comment: What's `pipeline_path`? I don't see it defined. Voting to close as lacking a [mcve] as it's now.

Comment: pipeline_path = "./data/temp/pipeline/"
i wrote that I checked it several times. this works as intended. checked with debugger.

Comment: That's a relative path. The linked question suggests providing absolute paths.

Comment: Found a mistake in (2), the line: result.label. Wrong numbers there. But now I have the problem, that  the same exception is throwing randomly. sometimes the NN is learning 5*128 batches, sometimes 14.. sometimes 0. 
Could the problem be, that the queue provides the data too slow?

Comment: That sounds unrelated. You can ask another question about it. Be sure to follow [ask].

Comment: @nbf77 Did you find your error?